# Subtracting a value in a sed expression

Tags: regex, sed

I have a bunch of dates in a logfile that use the day of year format instead of day of month format:

So I see:

```
2013-10-302
```

instead of

```
2013-10-29
```

I want them in day of month format. So I do:

```
sed "s/2013-10-302/2013-10-29/
```

But a problem with this approach is that I have several dates I need to convert.  I could do something like if the month is 10, then subtract 273 from the day in year. If the month is 9, subtract something else.

So even if there is no better approach, any tips on how I would just do it this way?  i.e. so if is month 10 subtract 273?

Thansk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `awk`

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    FS=OFS="-"
} {
    cmd="date -d "$1"-"$2"-01 +%j"; 
    cmd | getline offset; 
    $3=sprintf("%02d",$3-offset+1); 
    print
}' file
```

**Test**

Input file

```
2013-10-302
2013-11-310
2013-09-268
```

Output

```
2013-10-29
2013-11-06
2013-09-25
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the date in %Y-%m-%j format, where `%j` stands for day of the year.

What if you do this?

```
$ date -d "Jan 1 2013 + 302 days" "+%F"
2013-10-30
```

Put it in context, if you have a file like

```
$ cat a
2013-10-302
```

You can "clean" it up with the following steps:

```
$ cat a
2013-10-302
```

Get the old date and the 3rd field for days since 1 Jan:

```
$ old_date=$(cat a)
$ echo $old_date
2013-10-302
$ day=$(cut -d- -f3 <<< "$old_date")
$ echo $day
302
```

Calculate the real date and update the file:

```
$ new_date=$(date -d "Jan 1 2013 + $day days" "+%F")
$ echo $old_date, $new_date
2013-10-302, 2013-10-30
$ sed -i "s/$old_date/$new_date/g" a
$ cat a
2013-10-30
```